# Is there a way to load rda/RData data from R into SAS?

Tags: r, sas

I have plenty of `.rda` and `.RData` files from R statistical packageand would like to read them into SAS. Is there an (easy) way to do this?

Comment: are they just data frames? why not write to a csv and read that into sas? or maybe [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mdsug/65072/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1bl4ds513zp00n0z9twwsmkzoy8.htm)

Comment: Those are already .rda and .Rdata files. Not objects in R global environment.

Comment: @rawr's link would be a great way to go if you have SAS/IML licensed, otherwise why not just use R? ;)

Comment: You can convert them from .rda or .RData to a more portable format (like CSV) using R (`write.csv`) or something like Stat/Transfer.

Comment: Let's assume I don't Have R installed and can't install it Because of internet connection lack.

Comment: I don't think so: https://communities.sas.com/message/241238

Comment: Do you have a SAS/IML license?

Comment: You have to have R installed to use the IML facility to read R objects into SAS.

Comment: I think SAS/IML still needs R to connect to R, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get R installed, then you could execute R code within PROC IML (assuming your SAS installation is configured properly, which can be a problem), read the results into e.g. a R data.frame and get the results back as described in the SAS documentation examples. If you do not have the SAS/IML license but have R, write the output out from R into some format SAS reads easily (e.g. csv). If you cannot get R installed on your system, can someone else with R installed do that for you?

Otherwise, you may have to write a SAS program that can parse the RData format. However, that would be a measure of desperation. I believe you would find the documentation of the format [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Serialization-Formats) and some discussion of the not so clear documentation [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/02/r-rdata-file-format.html) (see [also](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000470.shtml))